# Is it possible to change the SQL_MODE for only one user only in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-mode

Is there a way to change the SQL_MODE for only one user in MySQL? 
I know I can change the SQL_MODE for a connection by executing the following query

```
SET SQL_MODE = '';
```

But the idea here is to change it always without having to set it every time. I am using a third party program to insert data into MySQL Server. So there is no way I can execute queries like changing the SQL_MODE every time. this is way I am looking for an option where I can permanently set it for a pacific user without having to change the entire server settings.

Thanks

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31447

Comment: Thank you... That was the correct answer. I tested it on 5.6.13 and it also worked.